# Why dichlorobenzene doesn't show geometrical(cis/trans) isomerism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

As it has restricted rotation due to the presence of a double bond, it should show geometrical isomerism. Then, why *doesn't* it show cis/trans isomerism?

Comment: 1. The trans form will not be formed because it leads to too much strain in the small ring ring. 2. It will lose aromaticity.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Are you sure you have the right molecule? [Dichlorobenzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichlorobenzene) is basically a benzene ring, there is no real isomerism to speak of. Do you mean something like azobenzene?

Comment: Geometrical isomerism is shown by linear as well as cyclic chain. So why can't we talk about benzene ring? And yes, the question is correct

Comment: Benzene, as an aromat, does NOT contain double bonds like 2-hexene, or any other olefin. Read two pages further in your textbook.

Comment: I have read my textbook but benzene ring wasn't mentioned there that's why i asked this question

Comment: The questions are a bit similar except the fact that we are discussing about a different compound

Comment: 1-bromo-2-chlorobenzene is in principle almost the same compound, at least in the sense of stereochemistry, it behaves exactly the same. That why I closed it as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

There are dichlorobenzene isomers but not cis-trans. You can have ortho (where the Cl atoms are close together), para (where the Cl atoms are opposite) and meta where Cl atoms are one C atom apart. Lets examine the ortho-dichlorobenzene which part of it "looks" the most like cis-1,2 dichloroethene (which also has a trans isomer). Is there any way you could make the Cl atoms in ortho-dichlorobenzene to be as far apart as in trans-1,2 dichloroethene without breaking any bonds? The answer should be no and this is why cis-trans isomerism in common substituted aromatic rings makes no sense.